# Map-Reduce <Key, Value> pair Key being a time interval

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a text file having on each row the following:

```
2018-11-27T08:06:11, 4.000000, 6.000000

2018-11-27T08:06:13, 9.000000, -1.000000

2018-11-27T08:06:15, 2.000000, -3.000000

2018-11-27T08:06:17, 1.000000, 9.000000

2018-11-27T08:06:19, 5.000000, -1.000000
```

What I need is after applying Map-Reduce the output to look like this:

```
2018-11-27T08:06:00 -> 2018-11-27T08:06:30, 9.000000, 9.000000
```

The [Values] are just the maximum value from a 30 seconds interval, but I have difficulties how to create that "Time interval" key. 
Basically I want my keys to be 30 seconds time interval.

I am new to Hadoop and Map-Reduce so any advice, idea, resource or code snipet would be extremely appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

[EDIT]

I managed to implement this Map-Reduce, it works for my case but for some reason the output displays besides the desired one, some data from the input file. 
Do you have any idea why?

Here is the class, I left a comment in code to the line which cause me problems.
If I delete that line it doesn't work anymore, but with that line written I have that awkward output(containing data for my input + the desired output)

The problem is in "reduce" method at the bottom.

```
public class SensorMapReducer
{
    public static class SensorMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String line = value.toString();

            if(line.startsWith("s"))
                processSensorLine(line,context);
            else
                processSimulatorLine(line,context);
        }

        private void processSensorLine(String line, Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String[] values = line.split(",");

            Calendar gc = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(values[1]);

            Text bucket = new Text(String.format("%4d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:00Z",
                    gc.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    gc.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
                    gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    gc.get(Calendar.HOUR),
                    gc.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));

            context.write(bucket, new Text("ACC," + values[2] + "," + values[3] + "," + values[4]));
            context.write(bucket, new Text("GYRO," + values[5] + "," + values[6] + "," + values[7]));
            context.write(bucket, new Text("MAG," + values[8] + "," + values[9] + "," + values[10]));
            context.write(bucket, new Text("REST," + values[11] + "," + values[12] + "," + values[13] + "," + values[14]));
        }

        private void processSimulatorLine(String line, Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String[] values = line.split(",");

            Calendar gc = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(values[1]);

            Text bucket = new Text(String.format("%4d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:00Z",
                    gc.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    gc.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
                    gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                    gc.get(Calendar.HOUR),
                    gc.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));

            context.write(bucket, new Text("PF" + values[6]));
        }
    }

    public static class SensorReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
    {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            XYZ acc = new XYZ(), gyro = new XYZ();
            Single mlux = new Single(), temp = new Single(), pressure = new Single(), rh = new Single();
            int pass = 0, fail = 0;

            for(Text value : values)
            {
                String val = value.toString();
                if(val.startsWith("ACC"))
                    acc.process(val);
                else if(val.startsWith("GYRO"))
                    gyro.process(val);
                else if(val.startsWith("REST"))
                {
                    String[] vals = val.split(",");
                    mlux.process(vals[1]);
                    temp.process(vals[2]);
                    pressure.process(vals[3]);
                    rh.process(vals[4]);
                }
                else if(val.startsWith("PF"))
                {
                    String pf = val.substring(2);

                    if(pf.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                        pass++;
                    else
                        fail++;
                }

                **// On my environment, if I don't do this it fails for no reason that I can see, but
                // I DO NOT WANT THIS LINE TO BE WRITTEN!!!!**
                context.write(key,new Text(val));
            }

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            acc.append(sb);
            sb.append('\t');

            gyro.append(sb);
            sb.append('\t');

            mlux.append(sb);
            sb.append('\t');

            temp.append(sb);
            sb.append('\t');

            pressure.append(sb);
            sb.append('\t');

            rh.append(sb);
            sb.append('\t');

            sb.append(pass);
            sb.append('\t');

            sb.append(fail);

            context.write(key, new Text(sb.toString()));
        }
    }

    private static class Single {

        private int val, count, min, max;

        private void process(String val)
        {
            int v = Double.valueOf(val).intValue();

            this.val += v;
            this.count++;

            max = max > v ? max : v;
            min = min > v ? min : v;
        }

        public void append(StringBuffer sb)
        {
            if(count > 0)
                sb.append(val/count);
            else
                sb.append("");

            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(min);
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(max);
        }
    }

    private static class XYZ {
        double x, y, z;
        double xMax = 0.0, yMax = 0.0, zMax = 0.0;
        double xMin = 0.0, yMin = 0.0, zMin = 0.0;
        int count = 0;

        public void process(String val)
        {
            String[] vals = val.split(",");

            double x = Double.valueOf(vals[1]);
            double y = Double.valueOf(vals[2]);
            double z = Double.valueOf(vals[3]);

            xMax = xMax < x ? x : xMax;
            yMax = yMax < y ? y : yMax;
            zMax = zMax < z ? z : zMax;

            xMin = xMin < x ? x : xMin;
            yMin = yMin < y ? y : yMin;
            zMin = zMin < z ? z : zMin;

            this.x += x;
            this.y += y;
            this.z += z;

            count++;
        }

        public void append(StringBuffer sb)
        {
            sb.append(x/count);
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(xMin);
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(xMax);
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(y/count);
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(yMin);
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(yMax);
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(z/count);
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(zMin);
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(zMax);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");

        job.setJarByClass(SensorMapper.class);

        job.setMapperClass(SensorMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(SensorReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(SensorReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Can you please help me with any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Use the time window function, for some examples see http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/introduction-to-spark-two-part-5/

Comment: @sramalingam24 OP is asking for help with MapReduce and not Spark.

Comment: @TheRichUncle - what have you tried so far? Show us your progress and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @BenWatson Hello! I managed to implement a solution, but I have some issues. Can you take a look and give me an opinion? Thanks!

Comment: @TheRichUncle feel free to raise a new question with any new issue you have and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @BenWatson there we go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223303/mapreduce-outputs-lines-from-input-file-besides-the-expected-result